# Значение слова "красный" в середине XIX века (у Тургенева)

Tags: значение-слов, литература, история

С некоторым удивлением встретил у Тургенева слово "красный" в следующем контексте:

> Кажется, я все делаю, чтобы не отстать от века: крестьян устроил, ферму завел, так что даже меня во всей губернии ***красным*** величают; читаю, учусь, вообще стараюсь стать в уровень с современными требованиям, — а они говорят, что песенка моя спета.
>
> *(Отцы и дети)*

Судя по тому, что слово "красный" выделено у самого Тургенева, оно было употреблено в новом для того времени значении.

И с одной стороны, со школы осталось знание, что красными стали называть революционеров уже во время революции/Гражданской войны (Красная армия, красные/белые), а это через 50 лет после "Отцов и детей". А с другой стороны, такое значение вполне укладывается в контекст: если ещё и не революционер, то хотя бы прогрессивный человек, старающийся встать "в уровень с современными требованиями". Получается, что "красные" (как термин) появились намного раньше революции. Так ли это, или Тургенев имеет в виду что-то другое?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, термин **красный** появился намного раньше революции 1917 года.

[**красный**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/843190)
**2.** Крайний левый по политическим убеждениям, революционный (***дореволюц.***).
*...меня по всей губернии красным величают...* (Тургенев).

В толковом словаре **[Даля](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/258886/%D0%9A%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%9D%D0%AB%D0%99)** (**1863-1866**) тоже есть кусочек:
...но красный, о человеке, в народе то же, что дикой, полоумный; а в переводе с франц. отъявленный республиканец.

О Николае Петровиче:

Рядом с сыном он провел три зимы в столице, прислушиваясь к «кипучим речам» молодежи и даже пытался участвовать в дискуссиях. Мало того. Великие идеи века, обсуждаемые в студенческих аудиториях, провинциальный помещик *смело вводит в практику.*

Множеством внешне мимолетных черт автор стремится подчеркнуть невиданный для своего времени *демократизм* Николая Петровича. Помещик стыдится называть себя владельцем двухсот крепостных душ. Старший Кирсанов признает себя имеющим власть лишь над десятинами земли, а имение, не без гордости, называет «фермой».
[**Герои второго плана романа Тургенева "Отцы и дети"**](https://dist-tutor.info/mod/book/view.php?id=35644&chapterid=2199)

P.S. Кратко переход от красного и белого знамен (символов противоборствующих сторон — республиканцев и монархистов; 1792) до окончательного противопоставления  “красные”/“белые” (Парижская коммуна; 1871) описан в статье Д. Фельдмана "Красные белые: советские политические термины в историко-культурном контексте" ([**часть II**](http://magazines.russ.ru/voplit/2006/4/fe1.html)).

Comment: Отдельное спасибо за "PS".